# Selecting First row on page load and select to other rows on arrow keys clicked in prime-react DataTable

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I need to select the first row of the DataTable on page load and select other row(single row) on keyboard arrow keys clicked.
I'm trying to achieve row selection using onKeyDown prop and here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { DataTable } from "primereact/datatable";
import { Column } from "primereact/column";

const ReactDataTable = ({ columnDefs, rowData, ...rest }) => {
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState(null);

  const newRowData = rowData?.map((each, index) => ({
    ...each,
    slectedRowIndex: index,
  }));

  const onRowSelect = (event) => {
    setSelectedRow(event.data);
  };

  const dataTableRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataTableRef.current) {
      if (newRowData?.length > 0) {
        setSelectedRow(newRowData[0]);
      }
    }
  }, [rowData]);

  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp" || e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      e.preventDefault();
      const selectedIndex = selectedRow
        ? newRowData.findIndex(
            (item) => item.slectedRowIndex === selectedRow.slectedRowIndex
          )
        : -1;
      let newIndex = selectedIndex;

      if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
        newIndex = selectedIndex > 0 ? selectedIndex - 1 : 0;
      } else if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
        newIndex =
          selectedIndex < newRowData.length - 1
            ? selectedIndex + 1
            : selectedIndex;
      }

      setSelectedRow(newRowData[newIndex]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="card react-data-table">
      <DataTable
        ref={dataTableRef}
        onRowSelect={onRowSelect}
        selectionMode="single"
        selection={selectedRow}
        onSelectionChange={(e) => setSelectedRow(e.value)}
        onKeyDown={(e) => onKeyDown(e)}
        value={newRowData}
        scrollable
        scrollHeight="400px"
        tableStyle={{ minWidth: "50rem" }}
        resizableColumns
        showGridlines
        columnResizeMode="expand"
        {...rest}
      >
        {columnDefs.map((col, i) => (
          <Column
            key={col.field}
            field={col.field}
            header={col.headerName}
            style={{ width: "20%" }}
          />
        ))}
      </DataTable>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ReactDataTable;
```

The first element on page load is selected but it is not selecting the other rows when arrow keys are clicked. How can I achieve that functionality.
It's only working if we click on any of the row in DataTable.
Can you help me where I'm doing wrong.